# Проблема с запуском проекта в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

моя проблема заключается в том, что я уже несколько часов не могу исправить ошибку с запуском проекта в Android Studio, выдает ошибку как на скрине. Пробовал переустановлять SDK, скачивал новые девайсы, но ошибку не уходит, буду благодарен за помощь [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я просмотрел папку данных девайсов, и заметил здесь слишком мало папок, разве так должно быть? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кириллица в пути к папке? Виртуализация включена?

Comment: Нет, я основную папку перекинул туда, где все названия папок на английском

Comment: Так просто переместить нельзя. Надо переустановить. И сделайте новый эмулятор